# How to set background-image responsive

Tags: css, responsive-design, background-image

Good evening,
I am working on website with "One page layout". And I have big problem with mobile responsivity.. Especially at menu and sections with background image. I will post my code bellow and could you please give me some advices, what to edit?
Thank you very much!

HTML:

```
<div id="menu">
<div id="content">
<div id="logo">
<a href="#uvod"><img src="style/img/logo.png" border="0"></a>
</div>   
<div id="nabidka">
<ul>
   <li href="about"><a href='#about'>O nás</a></li>
   <li href="cenik"><a href='#cenik'>Ceník</a></li>
   <li href="sluzby"><a href='#sluzby'>Služby</a></li>
   <li href="kontakt"><a href='#kontakt'>Kontakt</a></li>
</ul>
</div>   
<div id="socsite">
<table style="width: 210px; height: 80px;" border="0">
<tr><td width="70"><a class="fb" href=""></a> </td>
<td width="70"><a class="twitter" href=""></a>    </td>
<td width="70"><a class="youtube" href=""></a>        </td></tr>
</table> 

</div>   
</div>  
</div>

<div id="uvod" class="section">
<div id="content">
...text text text...
   </div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
#uvod {
background:url('img/bg-uvod.png') top no-repeat fixed; 
float:left;
width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
z-index: 1;
}

#menu {
background-color: #535353;
width: 100%;
height: 90px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: fixed;
top: 0;
z-index: 100; 
}

#logo {

width: 200px;
height: 90px;
margin-left: 1em;
  padding-top: 5px;
    float: left;
}
#nabidka {

width:550px;
height: 90px;

margin-left: 1.5em;
  padding-top: 5px;
float:left;

}
#socsite {

width:240px;
height: 90px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 7em;
  float: left;

}

#content {
width: 1200px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#uvod
{
  background: url('img/bg-uvod.png') no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Why not try cover?  If that doesn't work, try putting an absolute position div in the background, then set the background of that.

Comment: Thanks, it actually helped, but only for height. When I open it on mobile for example, sections where I use background image don't have 100% width. Menu has 1200px, sections with white background too, but image backgrounds have like 75% width... And second issue, when I zoom menu pannel, buttons go down, under gray pannel for menu and icons for social networks too... What should I do with this? I made it fixed, I gave it fix width (1200px)...

Comment: I'd suggest putting a position:absolute div in the background of your content and make it the size you need.  Then apply the background as described above to this new background div.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use the rule:

`background-size: cover;`

Add this to your `#uvod`.

This will cover the whole width of the screen and when your screen is made smaller it will shrink with it.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `background-size` property. Specifically, the `contain` and `cover` values.

Have a look at the documentation on MDN for more:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

This is a good read as well:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Scaling_background_images

Also, be sure to look at the browser compatibility table at the bottom of the first link and make sure it covers the browsers you're looking for.

If you are only targeting modern browsers, I might also recommend thinking about using SVGs for your background images, as they will look good at any size.